# rtl in material UI cause ruined my app appearance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, right-to-left, themeprovider

I setup my rtl configuration step by step in `v5mui`. Using:

- emotion as styled-engine
- stylis v4
- stylis-plugin-rtl v2

Every thing is OK but when using some complicated component my app appearance crashes.
There are a warning in terminal that I think will be the answer...
but I don't understand it.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/stylis-plugin-rtl/dist/stylis-rtl.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/hamid/Desktop/zahra/node_modules/stylis-plugin-rtl/src/stylis-rtl.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/hamid/Desktop/zahra/node_modules/stylis-plugin-rtl/src/stylis-rtl.ts'
 @ ./src/index.js 8:0-42 15:18-27
```

Comment: This is most likely related to how the dependency is being imported or installed. Have you correctly installed the dependency and how is it being imported in your project?

Comment: is there any problem when npm is running live server , while im installing some pakage?

Comment: Often times you'll need to restart the server for changes in your packages to be applied to your project. It depends on your build configuration.

Comment: some new pakage dictated to restart the server. but it may be recorrect after restart the server. im my situation. no!

Answer (score 4):

It was better to say which version did you use? for instance I used version **2.1.0** anyway, I have the same problem as you said with **v2.1.1** and I should use this version **v2.0.2** instead.

```
npm i stylis-plugin-rtl@2.0.2
```

I hope it can help you.

Best Wishes,

Parham